# Using Gtest how return different values in ON_CALL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Is it possible to return different values using ON_CALL WillByDefault?
for example

```
class FooMock {
  MOCK_METHOD0(foo, int());
}

void bar()
{
  FooMock mock;
  int f = 0;
  ON_CALL(mock, foo()).WillByDefault(Return(f));
  EXPECT_TRUE(f==mock.foo()); // this is correct
  f++;
  EXPECT_TRUE(f==mock.foo()); // it is failed, because ON_CALL returns f=0
}
```

Does exists some way to return new value of variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way, change your code to:

```
ON_CALL(mock, foo())
       .WillByDefault(ReturnPointee(&f));
```

Read more about `ReturnPointee` [in this link](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook) (in the `Returning Live Values from Mock Methods` section)